# How do I climb up and down the DOM Tree using element Tag names?

Tags: javascript

I know how to climb up and down the DOM using parentNode, children and id's, but I don't know how to access a sibling or child element by tag name alone.

This code example is a bit contrived, but I'm hoping you can use it to help me with a general answer to navigating using these element tag names.

```js
//fluff to create an example
const outArr = Array(10).fill(0).map( (el, i) => { return (
  '<p>Title ' + i + '</p>' +
  '<p>Decription ' + i + '</p>' +
  '<span>Other ' + i + '</span>' +
  '<button>Click to Like' + i + '!</button>'
  )});
const output = outArr.join(',');
document.getElementById('ex-container').innerHTML = output;

//targeting inside anon event function for simplicity
document.getElementById('ex-container').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.localName == 'button') {
      const curEl = e.target
      const parent = curEl.parentNode;
      
      //I can access the parent node. If I had id's, I know I could targert
      //children with those. How would I target the siblings, and from the
      //parentNode target a specific child by element tagName, such as p?
      console.log('curEl: ', curEl);
      console.log('parent: ', parent);
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<div id='ex-container'>
<!--  everything goes here -->
</div>
```

Bonus: how can I target the nearer p sibling by tag name?

Comment: Everything you want to do can be done with jquery or similar library with ease. To do it without jquery and straight DOM functions check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName and the rest of the functions defined on Element.

Comment: What do you mean by "nearer"? Because in the case you're showing, the nearest `p` to the `button` will be the following `p` with "Title " in it, unless it's the last `button`, in which case it will be different.

Comment: @Daniel Williams  I know how to target elements by tagName, I would like to know how to traverse them on the DOM. For ex: e.target.parentNode.span (but this won't work. I'm searching for the proper syntax).

Comment: @Mike McCaughan  I added two p elements to help this part of the question. I would like to target the nearest, or the p element of a certain index which belongs to the same parent node. So far, for the bonus portion, element.closest() is the best solution I've found.

Comment: @IsaacB `e.target.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")` it is. To get only the span next to the button, I would recommend to put each group inside a grouping element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added some properties to address the questions commented in source (couldn't understand question). Details are comment by `/* */` in the Snippet.

**SNIPPET**

```js
//fluff to create an example
const outArr = Array(10).fill(0).map((el, i) => {
  return (
    '<p>Title ' + i + '</p>' +
    '<p>Decription ' + i + '</p>' +
    '<span>Other ' + i + '</span>' +
    '<button>Click to Like' + i + '!</button>'
  )
});
const output = outArr.join(',');
document.getElementById('ex-container').innerHTML = output;

//targeting inside anon event function for simplicity
document.getElementById('ex-container').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  /* Compare the currentTarget to the target, this way it
  || will give you target to whatever you clicked not just a
  || button 
  */
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
    const curEl = e.target
    const parent = curEl.parentNode;
    // How would I target the siblings,
    var bigBro = curEl.previousElementSibling;
    var lilBro = curEl.nextElementSibling;
    /* Collect all children of parent */
    var kids = parent.children;
    // from the parentNode target a specific child by element tagName, such as p?
    /* Same results for both with one difference being the
    || first one is "live" NodeList  the other "static"
    || NodeList. 90% of the time, it's safer to go "static"
    || using querySelectorAll() 
    */
    var paragraphsByTag = parent.getElementsByTagName('p');
    var paragraphsBySel = parent.querySelectorAll('p');

    console.log('curEl: ', curEl);
    console.log('parent: ', parent);
    console.log('bigBro: ', bigBro);
    console.log('lilBro: ', lilBro);
    /* Add .length property to get total number */
    console.log('Total Kids: ', kids.length);
    /* NodeLists are array-like but not true arrays, so use
    || Array.from() to convert them into true arrays. 
    */
    console.log('Paragraphs are: ', Array.from(paragraphsBySel));
  }
  /* Specific by tagName is almost an oxymoron. If you
  || want to target a specific element but only have
  || tagNames, then as you commented, by index is the way
  || to go.
  */
  console.log('The 6th paragraph is: ', Array.from(paragraphsBySel)[5]);

  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<div id='ex-container'>
  <!--  everything goes here -->
</div>
```

Comment: I'm going to go with this because it seems pretty comprehensive on movement and covers different ways to access the children using my code in the example. I still hope to find a way to live traverse and walk more efficiently around the DOM. Such as console.log(e.target == e.target.parentNode.span.previousElementSibling.previousElementSiblingp.nextElementSiblingbutton) //logs true

Comment: Try using jQuery, it has a feature called [chaining](http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/introduction/method-chaining/). Chaining allows one to link methods together. I usually don't suggest jQuery to beginners because I think it cheats them out of a proper understanding of JavaScript, but it looks as if you have a good grip on the DOM. If you are looking for the most complete method to traverse the DOM, [treewalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) is an option, but the syntax and operation are a tad different.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). You can use `querySelector()` on a node to select child nodes by selector. Ex.

```
const parent = document.getElementById('someID')
const firstP = parent.querySelector('p:first-child')
```

`parent` would ref the element with ID of `someID`, and from there we can use `querySelector` on `parent` to select the first `p` tag.

Here's a working example:

```js
const parent = document.getElementById('someID')
const firstP = parent.querySelector('p:first-child')

firstP.style.color = 'red'
```

```html
<div id="someOtherID">
  <p>First</p>
  <p>Second</p>
  <p>Third</p>
  <p>Fourth</p>
</div>
<div id="someID">
  <p>First</p>
  <p>Second</p>
  <p>Third</p>
  <p>Fourth</p>
</div>
```

You can use the related [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to create an array of matching elements and do something along the lines you want, like this:

```js
const parent = document.getElementById('someID')
const pees = parent.querySelectorAll('p')

parent.pees = Array.from(pees)

parent.pees[0].style.color = 'red'
```

```html
<div id="someOtherID">
  <p>First</p>
  <p>Second</p>
  <p>Third</p>
  <p>Fourth</p>
</div>
<div id="someID">
  <p>First</p>
  <p>Second</p>
  <p>Third</p>
  <p>Fourth</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That definitely helps! Do you know a way I could do this using general appended .methods to traverse to it? Such as e.target.parentNode.firstElement.p or something similar?

Comment: This gets me one step away from victory. I could now pseudo traverse by chaining the querySelector, such as e.target.parentNode.querySelectorAll('p')[0]. My hope is there there's a baked in way to traverse tags just like i can parentNodes, children and id's.

Comment: Might have to use a DOM library like jQuery, Umbrella or similar.